# .NET custom configuration: serializing DateTimeOffest properties using a culture-invariant / XML format?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I'm using a custom configuration section within an MVC web application I'm currently working on. Given the following property `MyProperty` of type `System.DateTimeOffset` within a custom `ConfigurationElement` implementation:

```
public class MyClass : ConfigurationElement
{
    /// other properties...

    [ConfigurationProperty("myDateProperty", IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTimeOffset MyDateProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTimeOffset)this["myDateProperty"];
        }

        set
        {
            this["myDateProperty"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain why this gets serialized within the config file using (presumably) the `en-US` culture, like so:

```
    <add key="..." myDateProperty="10/02/2017 12:19:38 +01:00" />
```

I would have hoped the value would have be serialized in a culture-invariant format or XML format, e.g.:

```
    <add key="..." myDateProperty="2017-10-02T12:19:38+01:00" />
```

How can I specify a culture-invariant / XML format for serializing date-related properties?

Additional details which may or may not be important:

- I'm writing the values to a separate config file (referenced within `web.config`);
- The target .NET Framework is v4;
- The application's `Thread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentUICulture` are both set (implicitly) to `en-GB`;
- The same issue also occurs if I change the type to `System.DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

For me works fine:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new MyCultureInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name);
```

**MyDateTimeFormat:**

```
public class MyCultureInfo : CultureInfo
{
    ......implement constructors       

    private DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormatInfo;
    public override DateTimeFormatInfo DateTimeFormat {
        get
        {
            if (dateTimeFormatInfo == null)
            {
                var dateTimeFormatInfo = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
                dateTimeFormatInfo.FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK";
                dateTimeFormatInfo.LongTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK";
            }
            return dateTimeFormatInfo;
        }
    }
}
```